# Pluguin CDN Cloudflare or Lite Speed?

Tags: cloudflare, litespeed

I have installed the Lite Speed Cache plugin on my Wordpress directly from the server.
Also Cloudflare, my question is it better to disable Cloudflare and use Lite Speed CDN.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

scenario 1:
You could try to use different CDN. Then you could compare which performance/security/cost is better for your site.

scenario 2:
You could try to use both CDN to serve your website.
please see the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5JCiHmAjzk

- Use QUIC.cloud CDN serve the dynamic content
- User cloudflare CDN to serve the static content

My suggestion: if you want to use fully features, you need to use LiteSpeed Cache plugin and QUIC.cloud.